# invalid level number 'EXEC' error in OpenCOBOL

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

this is my code Here :

```
  ******************************************************************
  *  Open Cobol ESQL (Ocesql) Sample Program
  *
  *  FETCHTBL --- demonstrates CONNECT, SELECT COUNT(*), 
  *               DECLARE cursor, FETCH cursor, COMMIT, 
  *               ROLLBACK, DISCONNECT
  *
  *  Copyright 2013 Tokyo System House Co., Ltd.
  ******************************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION              DIVISION.
  ******************************************************************
   PROGRAM-ID.                 FETCHTBL.
  ******************************************************************
   DATA                        DIVISION.
  ******************************************************************
   WORKING-STORAGE             SECTION.
   01  D-EMP-REC.
       05  D-EMP-NO            PIC  9(04).
       05  FILLER              PIC  X.
       05  D-EMP-NAME          PIC  X(20).
       05  FILLER              PIC  X.
       05  D-EMP-SALARY        PIC  --,--9.

   EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.
   01  DBNAME                  PIC  X(30) VALUE SPACE.
   01  USERNAME                PIC  X(30) VALUE SPACE.
   01  PASSWD                  PIC  X(10) VALUE SPACE.
   01  EMP-REC-VARS.
       05  EMP-NO              PIC S9(04).
       05  EMP-NAME            PIC  X(20) .
       05  EMP-SALARY          PIC S9(04).
   01  EMP-CNT                 PIC  9(04).
   EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.

   EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA END-EXEC.
  ******************************************************************
   PROCEDURE                   DIVISION.
  ******************************************************************
   MAIN-RTN.
       DISPLAY "*** FETCHTBL STARTED ***".
       
  *    WHENEVER IS NOT YET SUPPORTED :(
  *      EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR PERFORM ERROR-RTN END-EXEC.
       
  *    CONNECT
       MOVE  "testdb"          TO   DBNAME.
       MOVE  "postgres"        TO   USERNAME.
       MOVE  SPACE             TO   PASSWD.
       EXEC SQL
           CONNECT :USERNAME IDENTIFIED BY :PASSWD USING :DBNAME 
       END-EXEC.
       IF  SQLCODE NOT = ZERO PERFORM ERROR-RTN STOP RUN.
       
  *    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO HOST-VARIABLE
       EXEC SQL 
           SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :EMP-CNT FROM EMP
       END-EXEC.
       DISPLAY "TOTAL RECORD: " EMP-CNT.
       
  *    DECLARE CURSOR
       EXEC SQL 
           DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
           SELECT EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, EMP_SALARY 
                  FROM EMP
                  ORDER BY EMP_NO
       END-EXEC.
       EXEC SQL
           OPEN C1
       END-EXEC.
       
  *    FETCH
       DISPLAY "---- -------------------- ------".
       DISPLAY "NO   NAME                 SALARY".
       DISPLAY "---- -------------------- ------".
       EXEC SQL 
           FETCH C1 INTO :EMP-NO, :EMP-NAME, :EMP-SALARY
       END-EXEC.
       PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE NOT = ZERO
          MOVE  EMP-NO        TO    D-EMP-NO
          MOVE  EMP-NAME      TO    D-EMP-NAME
          MOVE  EMP-SALARY    TO    D-EMP-SALARY
          DISPLAY D-EMP-REC
          EXEC SQL 
              FETCH C1 INTO :EMP-NO, :EMP-NAME, :EMP-SALARY
          END-EXEC
       END-PERFORM.
       
  *    CLOSE CURSOR
       EXEC SQL 
           CLOSE C1 
       END-EXEC. 
       
  *    COMMIT
       EXEC SQL 
           COMMIT WORK
       END-EXEC.
       
  *    DISCONNECT
       EXEC SQL
           DISCONNECT ALL
       END-EXEC.
       
  *    END
       DISPLAY "*** FETCHTBL FINISHED ***".
       STOP RUN.

  ******************************************************************
   ERROR-RTN.
  ******************************************************************
       DISPLAY "*** SQL ERROR ***".
       DISPLAY "SQLCODE: " SQLCODE " " NO ADVANCING.
       EVALUATE SQLCODE
          WHEN  +10
             DISPLAY "Record not found"
          WHEN  -01
             DISPLAY "Connection falied"
          WHEN  -20
             DISPLAY "Internal error"
          WHEN  -30
             DISPLAY "PostgreSQL error"
             DISPLAY "ERRCODE: "  SQLSTATE
             DISPLAY SQLERRMC
          *> TO RESTART TRANSACTION, DO ROLLBACK.
             EXEC SQL
                 ROLLBACK
             END-EXEC
          WHEN  OTHER
             DISPLAY "Undefined error"
             DISPLAY "ERRCODE: "  SQLSTATE
             DISPLAY SQLERRMC
       END-EVALUATE.
  ******************************************************************
```

Comment: As answered by cschneid that's not "pure COBOL" but COBOL with embedded SQL, which in most cases needs a precompiler.
Other than that: I highly suggest to NOT use the old OpenCOBOL 1.1 any more but update to GnuCOBOL 3.1.2.

Comment: Is the question answered already? If yes, please mark the answer that worked for you like that, otherwise drop a comment allowing the answer to be improved - and in any case I suggest to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to stay with your well posted question and learn more about how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

This is not "pure COBOL", but COBOL with embedded SQL, which in most cases needs a precompiler.
As-is there is a word `EXEC` where in COBOL a level-number would be expected, therefore the message from your compiler is correct.

In order to compile this source with your COBOL compiler, use an `EXEC SQL` precompiler to convert the SQL statements into COBOL for you first, most likely the one that the sample program references: [`ocesql` - Open-COBOL-ESQL](https://github.com/opensourcecobol/Open-COBOL-ESQL/) (PostgreSQL only).

As an alterative you can also use other preparsers (likely with some adjustments, especially for the `CONNECT`); here's an incomplete list:

- [`esqlOC` - ESQL for GnuCOBOL/OpenCobol](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/contrib/HEAD/tree/trunk/esql/) (also works with other compilers, uses ODBC under the hood)
- [Gix ESQL](https://github.com/mridoni/gix), a recent addition, currently only as part of the Gix-IDE (GnuCOBOL only, currently uses a general ODBC or direct binding to PostgreSQL or MySql)

... and some proprietary variants (only to access their products)

- Oracle Pro*COBOL
- IBM DB2 precompiler
- ...